# How can I make sure Javascript array containing values with certain character remain unaltered, while I work on it?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have an Javascript array,

```
var example = [and, there,sharma<br, />, ok, grt]
```

Now I want to randomly delete some array values - but not those values which have

```
<br
```

in them, in the above example, I want to make sure

```
"sharma<br" is not deleted.
```

I also do not want to delete "/>".

Can anyone help me. I would really appreciate the answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This isn't a free coding service -- if you've made an attempt at solving this, please post what you've tried and we'll help you fix it.  If you haven't made any attempt, please do so before posting a question.

Comment: Pretty sure I saw the exact same question posted a few hours ago (since deleted)...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, that is not a valid array, unless you are missing the string quotes. Anyway, what you are searching for is [Array.Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). In your case :

```
var filtered = example.filter(v => v.indexOf("<br") != -1 || v.indexOf("/>") != -1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and help

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood the problem correctly, then you want to keep those entries in the array which have substrings `"<br"` and "/>"

If thats the case, you can try using javascript string method `includes()` to see if a string contains a particular substring.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript array must be created as below

```
var example = ["and"," there"",sharma<br","/>","ok"," grt"];
```

Using splice method , to delete the array values specifying the index positions.

array splice() method changes the content of an array, adding new elements while removing old elements.

Syntax
Its syntax is as follows −

```
array.splice(index, howMany, [element1][, ..., elementN]);
```

Parameter Details

index − 
   Index at which to start changing the array.

howMany − 
   An integer indicating the number of old array elements to remove. If howMany is 0, no elements are removed.

element1, ..., elementN − 
    The elements to add to the array. If you don't specify any elements, splice simply removes the elements from the array.

Return Value
Returns the extracted array based on the passed parameters.

```
var removed = arr.splice(2, 2);
```

This would remove your suggested output to be my assumption .

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort but the example array is dynamically created so we will not know its positon before hand.

Comment: That's finds me helpless .sorry.I'll try to your requirement.